# How do I fix an upper arm and shoulder not bending correctly?

Tags: rigging, bones, weight-painting

I'm not very sure how this happened but I assume this issues started when model wasn't in a T pose before I generated rig. When I tried to rotate my upper arm bone on the right shoulder to put it in a T pose this happened.

What I tried to do to fix it?
I tried weight painting it myself to see if that would fix but no change happened, I tried mirror weights, but it didn't mirror correctly I assume because it mentioned the vertices count error failed, so I tried merges all the vertices to see if that did anything to help with that but sadly did not. I would delete one side then mirror but afraid that would interfere with my shape keys. (Tried to do some research on this but unsure what problem I can even describe could match this.)

[image]

The file for it is here:
https://workupload.com/file/4gTJzAJVLA4

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Hello, if you think that the right part works, why don't you simply mirror it?

Comment: Like deleting the left arm and mirror the right arm? I thought about that moments ago but thought there was a better way. than that. (That might actually be the simplest way)

Comment: Problem. I tried but the arm doesn't line up correctly with the body and when I move it the other arms moves with it. When I go into object mode the arm ends up disappearing as well.

Comment: Yes because you have shapekeys, your rigging is a bit of a mess actually, your armature is not even symmetrical, you should clean the whole thing, keep the part that is correct, mirror it, symmetrize the armature, etc

Comment: As I feared. I made messes along the way. That will probably do then. Sadly, trying to do all that alongside keeping the right parts is getting harder as I go. (Might be because I don't know where to start or how to go about fixing the problems) Starting to wonder if restarting while taking into account would be easier lets see what I can do about it.. At least I know why it's messing up so much. This old project needs a remodel and update. THANK YOU!